# Rails - Email Confirmation - RecordNotFound Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, email-validation

I want an email to be sent when a user registers. This email should contain a link **that changes the account to a full user**. I want this email link to be a token for security.

- email_token  is a random generated token per user
- email_activation_token  is a boolean saying if the user completed registration or not

**Currently**: I get the email to send but when I click the link I get this error.

### ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#accept_invitation

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

**Link Sent** `http://localhost:3000/users/accept_invitation.P3Iu5-21nlISmdu2TlQ08w`

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end

    def accept_invitation
        @user = User.find(params[:email_token])
        @user.email_activation_token = true
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
    end
  end
end
```

**registration_confirmation.html.haml**

```
Confirm your email address please!

= accept_invitation_users_url(@user.email_token)
```

**user.rb model**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

      attr_accessor :password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
      before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
      before_create { generate_token(:email_token) }

      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$/
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates :password, :on => :create, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because in your accept_invitation method calls find on the User model expecting an id and you are passing the email_token parameter.

Try this..

```
def accept_invitation
  @user = User.find_by_email_token(params[:email_token])
  @user.email_activation_token = true
  @user.save
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you are doing:

```
User.find(params[:email_token])
```

This will attempt to find a user with an id that is equal to the email token passed in by the params. I think you are really trying to do something more like:

```
User.find_by_email_token(params[:email_token])
```

The find method will raise an exception if no record with the given id can be found. You need either need to be able to find by the token or to get the id of the record from the token.